# what is the savedsearch rest api url for netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I would like to access Netsuite `savedSearch` rest API url to import data in Magento 2.

Here is example of rest api to access items from netsuite

```
https://xxxxxxxxx.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryItem
```

Anybody knows url of Netsuite savedsearch Rest API ?
I want just netsuite savedsearch rest api url.

Answer (score 0):

For This you have to go through this whole document.

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSTRW/NSTRW.pdf

You have to setup each and every step mentioned in this document.

The xxxxxxxxx part in URL will be replaced with your account name once you create an account as mentioned in the document.

Comment: unfortunately, netsuite rest api does not support saved search,only soap api supports saved search